# Object parameters inputted from a get routing method are being stored as an object inside an object parameter

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, url-routing

Im trying to build a router that lets you save objects into an array using the data inputted client side through a get method. However, its saving the client side inputs within one of the object keys defined by the class constructor, instead of asigning them each to their proper keys.

The code used is as follows:

Server code

```
const express = require('express')
const fs = require('fs')
const app = express()
const routeCarrito = require('./routers/routerCarritos.js')
const routeProducto = require('./routers/routerProductos.js')

app.set('views', './views')
app.set('view engine', 'pug')

app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}))
app.use('/api/productos', routeProducto)
app.use('/api/carrito', routeCarrito)

const PORT = 8080
const server = app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`El servidor esta escuchando en el puerto: ${server.address().port}`)
})
server.on('error', error => console.log(`Error en el servidor ${error}`))
```

routeProductos Router code with object class

```
const express = require('express')
const fs = require('fs')
const routeProducto = express.Router()
routeProducto.use(express.json())
routeProducto.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}))

class Producto{
    constructor(id, timestamp, nombre, descripcion, codigo, urlFoto, precio, stock){
        this.id = id;
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
        this.precio = Number;
        this.urlFoto = urlFoto;
        this.codigo = codigo;
        this.stock = stock;
    }

    //Receives a product, saves it to the array file and returns the object's assigned id.
    save(nombre,descripcion,codigo,urlFoto,precio){
        fs.readFile('./arrays/productos.txt', 'utf-8', (error, contenido) => {
            if (error){
                console.log(error);
            } else {
                let productos = JSON.parse(contenido)
                let id = 1
                productos.map(producto => {
                    if(producto.id != null){
                        id++
                    }                    
                })
                let timestamp = new Date().toLocaleString()
                let stock = 1
                productos.map(producto => {
                    if(producto.stock != null){
                        stock++
                    }                    
                })
                let productoPush = {id, timestamp, nombre, descripcion, codigo, urlFoto, precio, stock}
                productos.push(productoPush)
                fs.promises.writeFile('./arrays/productos.txt', JSON.stringify(productos, ',', 2))
                    .then(() => console.log(`Producto guardado, su id es ${id}`))
                    .catch( error => console.log(error))
                }          
            });
    }
}

let productos = [];
const producto = new Producto();

routeProducto.post('/', (req, res) => {
    producto.save(req.body)
    res.send(`El producto "${req.body.nombre}" ha sido agregado al listado.`)
});

module.exports = routeProducto;
```

And an empty array in a 'productos.txt' file for it to work.

When you run the server and try to post a new object, it'll do it, but save all the parameters given to the post method into the 'nombre' key of the final object, instead of assigning each to their proper keys, and I dont know where the error is, aside from it most likely happening in the save() method.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by changing the `let productoPush` variable that listed every object key and instead have it use spread syntax, from:

```
let productoPush = {id, timestamp, nombre, descripcion, codigo, urlFoto, precio, stock}
```

To:

```
let productoPush = {id, timestamp, ...productoNuevo, stock}
```

And then declared the productoNuevo variable inside the router to pass along the key values from the client input:

```
    routeProducto.post('/', (req, res) => {
    let productoNuevo = req.body
    producto.save(productoNuevo)
    res.send(`El producto "${req.body.nombre}" ha sido agregado al listado.`)
});
```